# How to set border setting in different colors using Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am facing a small issue regarding border setting in multiplot. Though I am following a few examples available but still missing top and bottom lines.

here is the code

**

```
set multiplot
set border lw 2
set origin 0.05,0.49
set size 0.38,0.45
set yrange [-1.5:1.0]
set xrange [0:2.17106]
set ylabel "E-E_F (eV)" offset 0.5 font "Times-Bold, 35"
set ytics 0.5 font "Times-Bold, 35"
unset xlabel
#set title "Cubic" font "Times-Bold,35"
set label "a)" offset -1,12 font "Times-Bold,40"
plot "bands_cs.dat" using 1:($2--.3095296750)  w l lc "black" lw 2 notitle, "bands_cs.dat" every :::32::32 u 1:($2--.3095296750) w l lc rgb "blue" lw 3 notitle,"bands_cs.dat"   every :::33::33 u 1:($2--.3095296750) w l lc rgb "blue" lw 3 notitle,"bands_cs.dat" every :::34::34 u 1:($2--.3095296750) w l lc rgb "red" lw 3 notitle,"bands_cs.dat" every :::35::35 u 1:($2--.3095296750) w l lc rgb "red" lw 3 notitle

set origin 0.38,0.49
set size 0.14,0.483
unset arrow
unset xtics
unset label
unset yrange
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
#set xrange[0:2000]
set xtics 1000
set yrange[-1.5:1.0]
set border 1+2+4 lt rgb "black"
set title "{/Symbol s}^{AHE}(10^3 Scm^{-1}) "  font "Times-Bold,25"
set key opaque box right samplen 0.8 height 1.2

xmn=-50
xmx=2500
set ytics format "" nomirror
set xtics (" " 1000,\
        " " 2000 ) font "Times-Bold, 35"
set arrow from  xmn, 0.0 to  xmx, 0.0 nohead dt "-"
ymn=0.98
ymx=0
set arrow from 2100,-0.2 to 2100,0 nohead dt "-"
unset xlabel
#set xlabel 0,1,2
set xrange [xmn:xmx]
set y2range [0.95:1.02]
set border 8 lt rgb "dark-green" lw 2
set y2tics 0.1 nomirror textcol rgb "dark-green" font "Times-Bold, 30"
plot "cs_yx.dat" u 2:1 w l notitle ' lc rgb'black' lw 4,"strain_yx.dat" u 3:1 w lp axes x1y2 lc rgb "dark-green" lw 4 pt 7 ps 2  notitle
```

**
In short, i need to change one color side of the plot.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want all top and bottom borders black and only the right border of the 2nd plot in dark-green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to have the right y-axis of the 2nd plot in a different color (without y2tics), but the others borders in black. You can simply remove the right border via `set border 5` and add a green line via `set arrow`.

Check `help border` and `help margins` and `help arrows`.

**Script:**

```
### set border in different colors
reset session

set multiplot

    set margins 0,0,-1,-1   # l, r, b, t
    set origin 0.10,0.10
    set size   0.60,0.90
    set border lw 2
    set grid x,y
    plot sin(x)

    set origin 0.70,0.10
    set size   0.20,0.90
    unset ytics
    set border 5             # only top and bottom
    set arrow 1 from graph 1,0 to graph 1,1 lw 2 lc "green" nohead front   # "manual" border
    set xrange [0:10]
    set xtics add ('' 0)     # remove 0 label to avoid overlap with 10 of the 1st plot
    plot cos(x) lc "green"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** if you want to have ytics (actually, y2tics) on the right colored axis, you probably have to add a third dummy plot within the multiplot environment. Check the following example:

**Script:**

```
### set border in different colors including tics
reset session

set multiplot

    set margins 0,0,-1,-1   # l, r, b, t
    set origin 0.10,0.10
    set size   0.60,0.90
    set border lw 2
    set grid x,y
    plot sin(x)

    set origin 0.70,0.10
    set size   0.20,0.90
    unset ytics
    set border 5             # only top and bottom
    set xrange [0:10]
    set xtics add ('' 0)     # remove 0 label to avoid overlap with 10 of the 1st plot
    plot cos(x) lc "green"
    
    set border 8 lw 2 lc "green"
    set format x ''
    set xtics scale 0
    set yrange [GPVAL_Y_MIN:GPVAL_Y_MAX]    # yrange from previous plot
    set y2tics 0.2 nomirror
    set link y2 via y inverse y
    set format y2 ' '
    plot NaN notitle   # dummy plot, plots nothing

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked for me, Can you please tell me how to set ytics as green without labelling y axis

Comment: @ashice do you want the green y-axis with the same tics as the left black axis or different tics?

Comment: Thanks, @theozh, I made this, I really appreciate you taking you time and answering my question. Thanks alot.

Comment: @ashice you're welcome. Make sure in the 3rd plot that you `set y2tics` to the same tic interval (here 0.2) as the ytic interval in the 1st plot. I'm not sure if it can be done easily automatically. If you want to add a vertical and horizontal grid in the 2nd (right) plot you need to add `set grid x,y2` before the third plot command.

Answer (score 0):

This a variation of theozf's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71893443/318716).  While it doesn't directly address the OP's question, it may be helpful for anyone arriving here after Googling gnuplot multiplot border/tic colors. To create:

[image]

use the following gnuplot script:

```
set multiplot
    set title 'This is a multiplot title' noenhanced
    my_height_upper = 0.45
    my_height_lower = 0.55 # upper 45%, lower 55%
    my_height_start = 0.02
    set margins 0,0,1,-1 # l,r,b,t
    set key tc variable  # colored keys (optional)
    set xlabel ' '
    set xtics format ' '
    
# Plot the upper plot, a sqrt(x):
    set bmargin 0
    set origin 0.10, my_height_lower + my_height_start
    set size   0.80, my_height_upper
    set ylabel 'Square root abs' off 1.5, 0
    set xrange [-1:7]
    set grid x,y
    plot sqrt(abs(x)) lc 'blue'

# Setup for the two lower plots (actually three):
    set bmargin
    set tmargin 0
    set xrange [GPVAL_X_MIN:GPVAL_X_MAX] # keep xrange of upper
    set origin 0.10, my_height_start
    set size   0.80, my_height_lower
    unset title
    unset grid

# Plot sin(x):
    set border 2 lc "red"
    set ylabel 'Sine' tc 'red' off 1.5, 0
    set ytics nomirror
    set ytics add ('' 1) # avoid overlapping numbers
    set key left
    plot sin(x) lc 'red'

# Plot int(x):
    set border 8 lc "green"
    set y2label 'Integer' tc 'green' off -1.2, 0
    unset ytics
    unset ylabel
    set y2tics auto
    set key right
    plot int(x) axis x1y2 lc 'green'

# Finally add a black border, bottom ticks, and an xlabel:
    unset y2tics
    unset y2label
    set border 15 lc "black"
    set xtics format "%h"
    set grid x
    set xlabel 'This is the xlabel'
    set yrange [42:43] # dummy to suppress error msg
    plot NaN notitle

unset multiplot
```